# Get image captions for images on gallery post format metabox

Tags: metabox, gallery, post-formats, captions

I have a post format gallery. I have created a metabox to add my images:

```
function mytheme_show_post_gallery_metabox( $post ) {

wp_nonce_field( 'mytheme_post_gallery_metabox', '_mytheme_post_gallery_metabox' );
$gallery = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_mytheme_post_gallery', true );

?>
<a class="gallery-add button media-button button-primary button-large media-button-select" href="#" data-uploader-title="<?php _e( 'Add gallery images', 'mytheme' ); ?>" data-uploader-button-text="<?php _e( 'Add gallery images', 'mytheme' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Add gallery images', 'mytheme' ); ?></a>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <ul id="gallery-metabox-list">
        <?php if ( $gallery ) : ?>
          <?php foreach ( $gallery as $key => $value ) : $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $value ); ?>
            <li>
              <input type="hidden" name="_mytheme_post_gallery[<?php echo $key; ?>]" value="<?php echo $value; ?>">
              <img class="image-preview" src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>">
              <a class="change-image" href="#"><?php _e( 'Change | ', 'mytheme' ); ?></a>
              <a class="remove-image" href="#"><?php _e( 'Remove', 'mytheme' ); ?></a>
            </li>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<?php
}
```

This code allows me to add images to my gallery through a metabox. I am now trying to also get the caption for each image. I have been trying quite a few approaches but no luck so far.. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the attachment ID and convert to a post. From there the caption is stored on the post object.

```
$thumb_img = get_post( get_post_thumbnail_id() ); // Get post by ID

echo $thumb_img->post_excerpt; // Display Caption

echo $thumb_img->post_content; // Display Description
```

In your loop it would look like:

```
<?php if($gallery) : ?>
    <?php foreach($gallery as $key => $value) :
        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($value);
        $image_post = get_post($value);
        $caption = $image_post->post_excerpt;
```

How you want to output the value depends on you and your css expectations;

```
<p class="wp-caption-text"><?php echo $caption; ?></p>
```

---

An alternate would be to use [Caption_Shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Caption_Shortcode):

```
[caption]<image> Caption[/caption]
```

Comment: This works but only for the post thumbnail. I need to get the captions of the images I add to the post gallery on format post gallery through the code above.  I get the images with wp_get_attachment_image_src() on this line of code           <?php foreach ( $gallery as $key => $value ) : $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $value ); ?>
I am wondering if there would be a similar function to get the caption of each gallery image.

Comment: Sorry, just one other thing. How would I then echo out this caption on the post page front end?

Comment: I mean the front end of the post. After I get the images on my metabox I show them in a gallery in the front end like this             if ( !empty( $images ) ) {
             foreach ( $images as $image ) {
              echo
              '<li class="animated fadeIn">',
               '<figure>',
                 wp_get_attachment_image( $image, 'post-full-width' ),
               '</figure>',
              '</li>';
             }
            }  I am just wondering how I would show the caption here.

Comment: I have asked it here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/213319/how-to-show-post-format-gallery-metabox-image-caption-in-the-post-front-end