# How to show post format gallery metabox image caption in the post front end

Tags: metabox, gallery, post-formats, captions

After getting my images through a metabox for a gallery post format I have the following code to show them on the post front end:

```
<?php

    if ( !empty( $images ) ) {
        foreach ( $images as $image ) {

           echo
               '<li class="animated fadeIn">',
                    '<figure>',
                         wp_get_attachment_image( $image, 'post-full-width' ),
                    '</figure>',
                '</li>';
        }
     }
?>
```

I am just wondering now how to show the images captions on the front end along with the images also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add to [figcaption](http://html5doctor.com/the-figure-figcaption-elements/) on your front-end.

```
<?php

    if ( !empty( $images ) ) {
        foreach ( $images as $image ) {

           $image_post = get_post($image);
           $caption = $image_post->post_excerpt;

           echo
               '<li class="animated fadeIn">',
                    '<figure>',
                         wp_get_attachment_image( $image, 'post-full-width' ),
                         '<figcaption>', 
                               $caption, 
                         '</figcaption>',
                    '</figure>',
                '</li>';
        }
     }
?>
```

Comment: Sure did. You're the man!;) Thanks a lot. I have another couple of questions. Should I create new questions to ask those? One of them is Javascript, not sure if you would want to have at that one.

Comment: Thanks a lot dude. Here is one http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/213321/update-caption-for-metabox-gallery-images