# Featured image shortcode

Tags: images, shortcode, post-thumbnails, visual-editor, captions

Each post currently requires the [`featured image`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails) to be duplicated within the post several times.

Is there any way in which I could dynamically call the [`featured image`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails) back into the post rather than manually inserting the image again several times?

**UPDATE**

I would also like to be able to show the image's [`caption`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Caption_Shortcode) and [`permalink`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/) if possible.

Comment: The code supplied below has been great and works perfectly, but is there anyway to bring the cation text and post url through at the same time. I have searched around various places but cant seem to find a method of doing this. :(

Answer (score 9):

Register the [shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API), ideally in a plugin or functions.php if you have to.

```
add_shortcode('thumbnail', 'thumbnail_in_content');

function thumbnail_in_content($atts) {
    global $post;

    return get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID);
}
```

Add the [shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) to you post content.

```
[thumbnail]
```

---

If you want more features, see [this post](http://www.transformationpowertools.com/wordpress/insert-featured-image-into-post-content-shortcode) or the [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/6cQHzRjz).

---

**ADDING CAPTIONS AND LINKS**

```
add_shortcode('thumbnail', 'thumbnail_with_caption_shortcode');

function thumbnail_with_caption_shortcode($atts) {
    global $post;

    // Image to display

    $thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID);

    // ID of featured image

    $thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();

    // Caption from featured image's WP_Post

    $caption = get_post($thumbnail_id)->post_excerpt;

    // Link to attachment page

    $link = get_permalink($thumbnail_id);

    // Final output

    return '<div class="featured-image">'
    . '<a href="' . $link . '">'
    . $thumbnail
    . '<span class="caption">' . $caption . '</span>'
    . '</a>'
    . '</div>';
}
```

**RESOURCES**

- [`get_the_post_thumbnail`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/)
- [`get_post_thumbnail_id`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_thumbnail_id/)
- [`WP_Post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post)
- [`get_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post/)
- [`get_permalink`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/)
- [Shortcode API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API)
- [Get image captions for images on gallery post format metabox](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/213307/84219)

Comment: Thanks a million @jgraup - that worked perfectly first time for me. Is there anyway to really push this and get the displayed image to also pull through the image caption and post link as well. Thanks again. Allan

Comment: sorry thought i had closed it - :( cant find the option to set as answered or anything - only option is to delete it - :(

Comment: Thanks for the update on the code above, and sorry to be a pain but what would the shortcode be for this. I am currently using [thumbnail size='array( 150, 150)' align=right] but obs its not pulling through the caption or permalink. - thanks again -

Comment: I have read it, but will double check it. I would be happy to loose the size/align if i could get the other functions to work. :)

Comment: I am just checking it now, got the image and caption coming through. Just testing on features images from other posts. Sorry taking me a while to get head around the coding. Thanks for your help and advice, I have managed to actually learn something. ;)

Comment: Any chance you could mark this answered?